# python : pb with sorted function

Tags: python, sorteddictionary

I have a problem with a function of sorting. I have create a dictionary containing objects Ship. I try to sort out my dictionary by name of boats. The function of sorting works correctly, but I do not manage to update the dictionary. Say otherwise than make print ( sorted ) I have well the sorted out dictionary, but when I make a print ( Dict) it is not any more sorted out... The only way is to put a return in my function sorting... Thank you for your help

details :

class Ship(object):

```
def __init__(self, id, name=None, country=None):
    self.id, self.name, self.country = id, name, country
    self.position = []

def __repr__(self):
    return repr((self.id, self.name, self.country, self.position))


def add_position(self, position):
    latitude, longitude, datestamp = position[0], position[1], position[2]
    self.position.append(Position(latitude, longitude, datestamp))
    self.sort_position()

def sort_position(self):
    self.position = sorted(self.position, key=lambda x: x.datestamp)
```

class ShipDict(dict):

```
def __init__(self):
    self.__dict__ = {}
    pass

def sort_dict(self):
    print("Resultat de la fonction de tri : ",sorted(self.items(), key=lambda x: x[1].name))
    self = sorted(self.items(), key=lambda x: x[1].name)
```

Execution :

```
bateau1 = Ship(1,'Marchant', 'France')
bateau3 = Ship(3,'Zoo', 'Grece')
bateau2 = Ship(2,'Atlantique', 'Hollande')

Dict = ShipDict()
Dict[1] = bateau1
Dict[2] = bateau2
Dict[3] = bateau3

print("Dictionnaire avant tri: ",Dict)
Dict.sort_dict()
print("Dictionnaire après tri: ",Dict)
```

results :

```
Dictionnaire avant tri:  {1: (1, 'Marchant', 'France', []), 2: (2, 'Atlantique', 'Hollande', []), 3: (3, 'Zoo', 'Grece', [])}

Resultat de la fonction de tri :  [(2, (2, 'Atlantique', 'Hollande', [])), (1, (1, 'Marchant', 'France', [])), (3, (3, 'Zoo', 'Grece', []))]

Dictionnaire après tri:  {1: (1, 'Marchant', 'France', []), 2: (2, 'Atlantique', 'Hollande', []), 3: (3, 'Zoo', 'Grece', [])}
```

Comment: Python dictionaries are not ordered (except in Python 3.6, where it is an implementation detail)

Comment: To be more precise, Python dictionaries are not _ordered_.  Items are stored in an arbitrary order.  If you need to conserve the insertion order, use a list of tuples or `collections.OrderedDict` instead.